# Jquery Ajax request with link id

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've already read a lot of tutorials and forum posts but for every more I read, I get more confused. I think my problem is very easy to solve...
So, I have links with different Id's which I only want to have the number.

```
<a id="stream_1" class="change" href="javascript:void(0)">Stream1</a>
<a id="stream_2" class="change" href="javascript:void(0)">Stream2</a>
<a id="stream_3" class="change" href="javascript:void(0)">Stream3</a>
```

To get only the number I saw this code

```
$('[id^=strea_]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/strea_/g, '');

        /* Request to .php file */
        var request = $.ajax({
        url: "/request/ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : id },
        dataType: "html"
        });

      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
});
```

What I want to do now is: By clicking one of the links, I want the number given in the id to be send to a .php script, to change the content of a certain div

```
<?php
include '/var/www/jpanimes/scripts/php/connection/connection.php';
$streamId = $_POST['id'];

if($streamRequest = $con->prepare("SELECT link FROM stream WHERE id = ?"))
{
    $streamRequest->bind_param("i", $streamId);
    $streamRequest->execute();
    $streamRequest->bind_result($streamData);
    $streamRequest->fetch();
    $streamRequest->close();
}

echo $streamData;
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

On the click event you can get the ID:

```
 $('[id^=strea_]').click(function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/strea_/g, '');
 });
```

Another solution is to use data attributes like that:

```
 $('a.open_stream').on('click', function(event) {
      var id = $(this).data('myOwnID');

      /* handle here your id */

      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
 });

 <a class="change open_stream" href="#" data-myOwnID="1">Stream1</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my post, would the JQuery code be right this way using the first solution?

Comment: sounds like good. Little improvement: add on the click-Method an event parameter and use **event.preventDefault();** to stop the default link click event.

Comment: Well it's really my first try to make an Ajax request and I'm totally insecure, maybe you can take a quick look if this is right (see my first post)

Comment: $('[id^=strea_]').click(function(**event**) { - you need the bolded word.

Comment: I made as far as I could but again I have absolutely no idea what to do... I posted the php code which should fetch the data from the database and give the response to the jquery code but I have no idea what next to do...

Comment: what says your javascript console?

Comment: First: What do you want now?, Second: Javascript errors can be found at your console. Each webbrowser has that.

Comment: I simply want to change the content of a div with the content output from the database and the Console says nothing..

Answer (score 1):

try that. You make an ajax request but you dont specific, what happens after the ajax request is complete. Here you must set a **success** method to handle the output.

```
$('[id^=strea_]').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace(/strea_/g, '');

    /* Request to .php file */
    var request = $.ajax({
        url:    '/request/ajax.php',
        type:   'POST',
        data:   {
            id: id
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(new_html) {
            // Insert the HTML into an Element
            $('div.content').html(new_html);
        }
    });

    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried it with this code again and nothing happen, neither a error report or something. I think the better idea is making this with normal php until I get a better knowledge of php and jquery. But thank you anyway a lot for your help